# How to suppress LSP message from flickering the minibuffer height?

Tags: minibuffer, lsp

I am facing an annoying problem which makes working very unpleasant:
I am using Go LSP (backed by gopls) on Emacs 26.3 (9.0) on Mac.
While working on Go code often a message of the form

```
LSP :: computing fix edits: /Users/<really-long-filesystem-path>file.go:123:45: missing ',' in composite literal (and 7 more errors)
```

is displayed in the minibuffer. (The actual error "missing ',' in composite literal" is of no importance, it is just an example.) The problem is the very long file system path: It is so long that the message doesn't fit into one line and the minibuffer is made larger to allow for two lines.

As this message is displayed and removed regularly on very short intervals this lead to some kind of "flickering" of the minibuffer which constantly jumps from 1 to 2 lines height. This is very distracting.

Unfortunately I did not find any configuration option to suppress this message from LSP altogether or to somehow force the message to be 1-line only?

I think I could truncate-lines in the minibuffer but I'm fine with multiline messages in general, it is just the annoying flickering between 1- and 2-line heigh that I want to turn of.

Comment: How about trying?  `(setq max-mini-window-height 1)`  To see the options for customizing that variable, type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable`

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for the suggestion, this works! The drawback is that this limits the height to 1 also for the interesting messages :-( But the ugly flickering is gone!

Comment: I would suggest looking (with `grep`) for the function that generates the offending message and then let-bind the `max-mini-window-height` variable to a value of `1`, which will serve to only apply a custom setting of `1` for the limited purpose of the modified function.  If the library you are using is not built-in and if you need some help, then consider updating your question with a link to the Lisp source code so that another forum participant can search the code for the function that generates the offending message.